# Stokes' Theorem - Procedure Explanation

Tags: calculus

> Use Stokes' Theorem to evaluate the counterclockwise circulation of the field $F = y^2i -yj +3z^2k$ around the boundary of the ellipse in which the plane $2x+6y-3z=6$ meets the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 1$

Ok, so the hardest part for me is visualizing the region in space in question. I know that Stokes' Theorem lets me pick any closed surface whose boundary is C to calculate the counterclockwise circulation by applying the equality between the line integral and the double integral of the curl of F.

Could someone enlighten me on how to be good at starting such a problem and sketching out what is being asked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The surface to be integrated over is the part of the plane that is inside the cylinder, this will be the interior of an ellipse.

1. The first step would be to calculate the curl of $\vec F$
2. then to ensure that we are only dealing with the values of $\nabla
           \times \vec  F$ that are on the plane, substitute $z=\frac 13
           (2x+6y-6)$ in the resulting expression.
3. Finally integrate $\nabla \times \vec  F$ over the unit circle in
       the x-y plane $$\vec I = \int _{-1}^1 \int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}
       ^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} (\nabla \times \vec  F )\,dy \,dx $$

your case will be pretty easy because $\nabla \times \vec  F$ does not depend on $z$ and only has one non-zero component.

Answer (score 1):

What is being asked in the problem is to evaluate a line integral not by integrating along a path, but by integrating over a surface.  With Stokes' theorem, you are allowed to use any closed surface you want, as long as the boundary of the surface is exactly the same as the path of integration.

The first step is to calculate the curl of $\vec{F}$.  The direction of the curl will help you choose a surface over which to integrate.  The magnitude of the curl will be used to evaluate the surface integral.  The second step is to choose a surface to integrate over to make the surface integral as simple as possible.  Generally, surfaces that are parallel to the curl or perpendicular to the curl are selected.

To make your sketch, draw the cylinder and then sketch just any ellipse to represent the intersection of the plane and cylinder.  You don't have to worry what direction this plane is in, or its elevation, although that is not hard to do it.  After sketching an ellipse on the cylinder, sketch a circle going around the cylinder.  Put the circle somewhere along the cylinder so that it does not intersect the ellipse.

Now you have enough of a sketch to imagine the surface you want to integrate over.  One part of the surface is the interior of the circle.  The other part of the surface is that part of the cylinder between the circle and the ellipse.  Sketch the curl of $\vec{F}$ and the normal vectors to the surfaces, if you want.

The third step would be to make a sanity check on the rough sketch.  Would this work for any plane or do you need to make a more precise sketch?  Does it matter which circle you choose?  Does the surface form a "cap" over the elliptical path?  Have you addressed all of the features of the problem?

So now, you have a closed surface whose boundary is the path of integration.              Before you evaluate the integral over the circular region, look to see if you can simplify it further, possibly by integrating only part of the surface.